# Routing issue root of parent

Tags: angular, angularjs-routing, angular-routing

I have the following setup of my app:

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', redirectTo: ['Login']},
    {path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: '/dashboard', name: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
    {path: '/gamers/...', name:'Gamers', component: GamersComponent}
])
```

In my GamersComponent I have:

```
@Component({
    selector:'gamers',
    templateUrl: 'app/gamers/gamers.html',
    directives:[]
})

@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/addGamer', name: 'AddGamer', component: AddGamerComponent},
{path: '/editGamer', name: 'EditGamer', component: EditGamerComponent}
])

export class GamersController{
    constructor(){
    }
}
```

and my gamers.html:

```
<h1>Gamers</h1>
<a href="#" [routerLink]="['AddGamer']">Add Gamer</a>
<a href="#" [routerLink]="['EditGamer']">Edit Gamer</a>
<gamers></gamers>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My question is:

How can I create a link, which will redirect me to the 'Gamers', so that I can see content of `<gamers></gamers>` without any of its child in the `<router-outlet>`?

So far when I am redirecting to `Gamers`, I have the following error:

```
EXCEPTION: Link "["Gamers"]" does not resolve to a terminal instruction. in [['Gamers'] in NavigationComponent@5:20]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `routerLink` like this:

```
<a routerLink="['/Gamers']">Gamers</a>
```

This way you will use the routes configured in the root router instead of ones in the current route (the child one).

**Edit**

You need to define a default sub route for gamers:

```
@Component({
  selector:'gamers',
  template: `
    <h1>Gamers</h1>
    <a [routerLink]="['AddGamer']">Add Gamer</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['EditGamer']">Edit Gamer</a>
    <!--gamers></gamers-->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/', name: 'GamersHome', component: GamersHomeComponent, useAsDefault: true},
  {path: '/addGamer', name: 'AddGamer', component: AddGamerComponent},
  {path: '/editGamer', name: 'EditGamer', component: EditGamerComponent}
])
export class GamersComponent {
  constructor(){
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/rQluijSidf4tF1LZgKsG?p=preview

Comment: It seems that you need to define a default sub route for gamers. I updated my answer and provide a plunkr. Feel free to tell if it's what you expect as behavior...